# Playframework Scala Transform Request from Json to x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: scala, playframework

Hi I am new to Scala and Playframework. I am getting an ajax request that is json format and I need to make another request to another server with x-www-form-urlencoded format.

I have this code in the controller

```
  def getToken = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    WS.url("https://api.xxxx.com/v1/yyyy")
      .withHeaders(
        "accept" -> "application/json",
        "content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization" -> "Auth %s".format(apiKey)
      ).post(request.body) map { response =>
        Logger.info("response from get user: " +  Json.prettyPrint(response.json))
        Ok("ok")
    }
  }
```

I tried different ways but I can't get this working. Maybe I should do a formatter in the model. Which would be the best way to cast the request json to a request x-www-form-urlencoded?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

You just need to pass a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` to the post method.
If you have some keys and values you can easily construct such a `Map`.

For instance:

```
WS.url(url).post(Map("key1" -> Seq("value1"), "key2" -> Seq("value2")))
```

#### Details

As mentioned in [Form Submission section of Play WS docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-form-data), if you want to submit a form you have to pass a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` to the `post` method.

What you are passing here, instead, is a `JsValue` (because the `request.body` is of type `JsValue` because of the body parser type which is `parser.json`). So first you have to extract the set of key/value pairs from the json object and then construct a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` from it and pass it to `post` method.

For example if you are sure that the json object (extracted from the request body by body parser) is a JSON Object (not an Array or String or a Numeric Value) you can construct the needed `Map` easily (just for the first level key/value pairs):

```
def getToken = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  import play.api.libs.json.JsObject
  val json = request.body.as[JsObject]
  val formParamsMap = json.value.mapValues(_.asOpt[String].toSeq)
  WS.url("https://api.xxxx.com/v1/yyyy")
    .withHeaders(
      "accept" -> "application/json",
      "content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization" -> "Auth %s".format(apiKey)
    )
    .post(formParamsMap) map { response =>
  Ok("ok")
  }
}
```

Comment: @NaderHadhiGhanbari Thank you for your answer. I am getting closer to the solution. I tried the solution but with the short answer I am getting the values wrapped in List element, I think because of the Seq. With the detailed answer is not compiling I am getting "Cannot write an instance of scala.collection.Map[String,Seq[String]] to HTTP response."

Comment: Values should be wrapped in a `Seq`, that's exactly the type `post` method expects in this case (from encoded). I compiled the answer successfully (Play `2.3.9`) by the way.